# Inserting custom tab and Iframe into yahoo mail

Tags: javascript, yahoo-mail

I'm working on inserting a tab into Yahoo mail that would display an iframe with meebo in it.
This tab will act the same as the "Home" and "Inbox" tabs. These tabs are defined as tables in the "MainTabControl" div. Each tab controls the absolute position of a div which contains the content for that tab.

I have added a tab by inserting a table into the MainTabControl div using "Customize Your Web" firefox extension. The problem appears to be that yahoo's javascript (used to modify the page) is erasing my tab as well as the div containing the meebo iframe. Anyone tried something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) might give you more options.